# Не получается удалить зависшие запросы к базе данных

Tags: php, mysql

Есть проблема: Раз в день на сайте скапливаются запросы к бд с time>100 пробовал отлавливать эти запросы и делать kill их но они сново и снова появляются сразу же. Помогает только перезагрузка службы майскюель сервера. Вопрос почему так происходит что при kill появляются новые всеравно зависшие запросы даже если подряд 10 раз полностью все запросы удалить, то новые не отрабатываются а висят, а при перезагрузке сервиса бд все ок?есть ли какойто другой выход из ситуации на php скрипт сделать чтоб кроном его можно было запускать чтобы решать такого рода проблему автоматически?
Сам код на данный момент:
    `$result = mysql_query("SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST");
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $process_id=$row["Id"];
      if ($row["Time"] > 100 ) {
        $sql="KILL QUERY $process_id";
        mysql_query($sql);
      }
     }`

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется их не нужно удалять. Нужно оптимизировать запросы, делать что бы быстрее ходили, юзать кэш